# R32I sampler2D returns always 0

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a (default vertex and) fragment shader that should resize textures and scale their color by a specific factor for brightness correction.

The result is rendered into an GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8 framebuffer.

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec2 screenSize;
uniform float scale;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    vec2 coord = gl_FragCoord.xy / screenSize;
    color = texture(tex, coord);
    color *= scale;
    color.a = 1;
}
```

When I bind a R32I texture to tex, the output from the `texture` call in the red channel is always 0, despite non 0 data being in the texture.
I checked via apitrace that  the correct texture is bound to `tex` and it contains values that go up to about 200.
Normalizing this value should give an output of `9.3e-8` from `texture()`,
while `scale = 9.67e7`.

There are no error messages (besides performance warnings) neither from `glGetError` nor from the debug  callback.

What am I doing wrong? Is it forbidden to bind integer textures to (non integer) samplers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using an integer format, you will have to use an `isampler2D` instead of your sampler.

> So for samplers, floating-point samplers begin with "sampler​". Signed integer samplers begin with "isampler​", and unsigned integer samplers begin with "usampler​". If you attempt to read from a sampler where the texture's Image Format doesn't match the sampler's basic format (usampler2D with a GL_R8I, or sampler1D with GL_R8UI, for example), all reads will produce undefined values.

(Source: [www.opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Sampler_types))

Comment: Wow, I read exactly that page but some missed that. Now I feel dumb. I probably assumed that there would be an implicit conversion process from int to float like when doing `glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, data);` but I have no idea where I got that from.

Comment: @Nobody: It might help if you understood that `texture (...)` is a bunch of overloaded functions. The overload for `sampler2D` returns `float` or `vec4`, which isn't what you're after. The overload for `isampler`, on the other hand, returns `ivec4`. You can spot that [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/texture.xhtml) if you know how to read generic GLSL types; when you see `gvec` or `gsampler` in GLSL reference pages, it's a short-hand notation for all possible data representations (e.g. `gvec` is a generic type that could be `ivec`, `uvec`, `vec`).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Actually I was exactly after a `texture` function that would return the [0;1] normalized value of the integer. Now I have to do the normalization on my own, which is not much work but still work.

Comment: @Nobody: Ah, I gotcha. Yeah, that normalization process is undefined for this sort of thing. Integer data stays integer unless you do the conversion yourself. Fixed-point data on the other hand will be normalized; I'm not entirely sure if your application really and truly calls for an integer texture (it's very uncommon particularly from the description in your question)? If you just want normalized data from integers, you can make GL do that for you when you upload the texture image. `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32` is a single component 32-bit normalized type that might work better for you.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Well, the `glGetTexImage` call does the conversion for me (though not on the GPU :). As to the use of integer textures: It is a scientific computation where I need exact per pixel counts that could range up to billions so there is not much left. I just wanted a quick and dirty visualization of the raw data.